# Strange behaviour of ChainCode which requires altering version each restart

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I always have to alter the name or the version of the chaincode which i want to install on the peers so that the new changes apply that i made to this specific chaincode. 
The problem here is that before every start of the network i stop and remove every container via a script:

```
docker ps -aq | xargs -n 1 docker stop
docker ps -aq | xargs -n 1 docker rm -v
docker volume prune -f
docker network prune -f
```

What am i missing? What have i to do so that "old versions" of the chaincode are forgotten/deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also remove chaincode **docker Images** that were created. Find them and remove using commands similar to:

> docker images dev*
>
> docker rmi dev-peer.....

You may have a number of these if you have gone through a number of repeated tests.

Comment: its docker images -a to check the images @kajuken